# How to hide ImageView (landscape) if device is lying on a table or another straight surface?

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, hide

I am having some problems with my application.
In some Views I want to hide a textview or an ImageView, if the device is in the landscape orientation. I was testing on a real device now and got some problems with my code, if I was lying the device on a straight surface like a table, my code doesn't hide the Image/TextView.

In my **ViewDidLoad** I use this:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        // code for landscape orientation
        [textview setHidden:YES];
    }
```

and I use the following code, if the user **rotate** the device:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [textview setHidden:YES];


    } else {
        [textview setHidden:NO];

    }
}
```

The code works fine, when I hold the device in my hands, but it doesn't work if the device lies on a straight surface.

How can I handle this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone gyroscope/accelerometer works based on the gravity, and that requires moving the phone with some motion in space, if you get me. However if you want to define a certain event for that mode, you should include `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` in your code. See [UIDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW30) for more info.

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

Try something like this:

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) || 
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp))
{
    //your code for landscape orientation 
    //[textview setHidden:YES;
}
```

Comment: if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) || UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp))
    {
        // code for landscape orientation
        [textview setHidden:YES];
    }                                                                    This doens't work. Why?

Comment: thx for answear, but doesn't work, maybe change sth. the third line??

Comment: Whoops! Of course that needed to be changed! Sorry for the mistake. I updated it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check when the phone is lying flat. use `UIAccelerometer`.

[image]

in .h set delegate

```
@interface AccelerometerViewController : UIViewController 
    <UIAccelerometerDelegate> {
}
```

in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self;
    accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/1.0f;       

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{

    //this checks if flat down
    if (acceleration.z < -1.0)
    {
        //this checks if rotate left
        if (acceleration.x < (-0.00) && acceleration.y > 0.00)
        {
            NSLog(@"rotate left");
            //hide textView here
        }
        //this checks if rotate right
        if (acceleration.x > 0.0 && acceleration.y > 0.00)
        {
            NSLog(@"rotate right");
            //hide textView here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: - (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel
        didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

    
    //if else statement checking if acceleration.x = 0.0 and acceleration.y = 0.0 and acceleration.z = -1.0
    //do you stuff...
    
    if (acceleration.x == 0.0 && acceleration.y == 0.0 && acceleration.z == (-1.0)) {
        [logo setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        [logo setHidden:NO];
    }
}
But it doesn't work?

Comment: thx for this. Only small problem it works only if I lay down the table, not if the device already lay on the table:

Comment: updated answer. don't forget `accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/1.0f; `